# How can I emit particles without them overlapping each other?

Tags: particles

How do I make a particle fit perfectly around a torus without absorbing or immersing each other in blender particle system. I made the torus the emitter, and use the sphere as the particle. I have tweak the particle number and some other things. Is there any other way I can achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Please place a second image in your question and leave the first if possible.  In the comment below you mentioned improved. Please show second improved image.  So we can understand what improvement means visually.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Grid distribution to place the particles regularly over the surface. Increasing the associated 'Random' setting moves each particle by a random amount giving a less regular appearance if desired.

[image: grid particle distribution]

Answer (score 1):

Consider reducing the size of your particles.

Then balance this with the number of particles.

This control is in the particle render panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped but the children still collide with each other