# Removing overlapping objects, made with particles

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, particles

I have some "bricks" that I put on an object with the particle system, but many of them are overlapping. 
I could use "random size" in the particle menu, but i want to keep the bricks somewhat uniform size.

Is there a way to avoid this with any of the options in the particle menu? Or, maybe after converting the particles to meshes, would it be possible to remove the overlapping ones ?

It is a static scene, no physics are involved.

[image: overlap1]

[image: overlap2]

Comment: Related question: [How can I emit particles without them overlapping each other?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43485/how-can-i-emit-particles-without-them-overlapping-each-other?rq=1). And also: [How to use emitter for generating thick forest so that trees would not intersect?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/how-to-use-emitter-for-generating-thick-forest-so-that-trees-would-not-intersect/36909#36909)

Answer (score 3):

go to emit from tab in particle system settings (you have to have the advanced checked), there you should have selected faces by default (if you didn't change it), then select one in particles/face.
Before:
[image]
After:
[image]
Faces:
[image]

If this doesn't work for you (you have too small faces or something) you can convert the particle system (mdifiers - particle system - convert) and then delete the overlapping bricks.

Comment: now there's no overlapping between bricks, but the the two ricks from the group are in some places on top of each other. and the order is too much perfect, i like it to be a bit random. i guess ill convert it and delete it manually for now +_+

Comment: http://oi67.tinypic.com/hsos3d.jpg

Comment: I once asked a similar question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40270/how-to-make-forest-with-different-types-of-trees       You might want to look at it too