# How to stagger particles to prevent overlap?

Tags: particles

I have a particle system in which some of the particles overlap, no matter what I do, and this causes unsightly intersecting polygons.

I tried various settings with both Random and Jitter modes, but nothing fixed the overlap problem. I also tried limiting the particle count to one particle per face, but Blender is apparently ignoring that.

If anyone knows what settings can be changed to keep particles from overlapping one another, please share. Thanks

Comment: Related questions: [How can I emit particles without them overlapping each other?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43485/how-can-i-emit-particles-without-them-overlapping-each-other?rq=1), [How to use emitter for generating thick forest so that trees would not intersect?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/how-to-use-emitter-for-generating-thick-forest-so-that-trees-would-not-intersect/36909#36909) and [Removing overlapping objects, made with particles](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44622/removing-overlapping-objects-made-with-particles?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks Carlo - I liked your answer on the question from [the second link you posted there](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/how-to-use-emitter-for-generating-thick-forest-so-that-trees-would-not-intersect/36909#36909). The info helped me to understand the nature of the problem and then I found another sort of solution that I explained in a comment there. Maybe I will go into it in more detail as an answer here.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for blender 2.8? The UI changed quite a bit; some settings are missing.