# How to stop particles from overlapping?

Tags: particles

I'm having an overlap problem when emitting particles.

[image]

[image]

[With this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43485/how-can-i-emit-particles-without-them-overlapping-each-other) I tried the face and grid options in the particle settings.

[image]

Yet I get the same result. How can I have separate meshes or no overlapping of the meshes. Are there any other settings that would work?